# Oil stopper of Shimano oil funnel: what's its sharp end for?

Tags: shimano, brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

Shimano instructs to insert the sharp end of the "oil stopper" to bleed the brakes:

[image: "The other end" of the oil stopper]

What is this for? I would expect that the oil should just flow from/to the funnel when pumped into the system with the syringe from the caliper bleeding screw. The other, wide end of the oil stopper, with the o-ring, is obviously needed to prevent oil flowing out when the funnel is being unscrewed from the brake lever; this is clear. But why does one need to insert the sharp end?

Comment: A guess is there are two different funnel/stoppers versions (old/new maybe). One the narrow end is the stopper, the other the wide end. Cost of changing drawings for something so obvious to the user is not worth it.

Comment: @mattnz my question still is - what is the purpose of inserting the sharp end of the stopper into the funnel during pumping the oil from the caliper.

Comment: I think this is old information. Current funnels do not have this feature.

Comment: https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/si/BR01A/SI-BR01A-001-ENG.pdf

Comment: Possibly this keeps the stopper in place so as not to get mislaid, without blocking the flow. The newer funnels allow the stopper to be clipped to the side out of the way.

Comment: @Noise 's suggestion is the most logical to me so far, perhaps it just holds the stopper hands-free. In the original doc SI-0061A-002-00, the sharp end is inserted while the oil flows, so it can't be blocking the flow (much?). The o-ring side is shown to be inserted when the flow is stopped.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing is for you to try it and then can answer with your findings

Answer (score 1):

When you want to remove the funnel from the brake lever, you put oil stopper into funnel where the oil goes out. It blocks the oil exit, so oil in the funnel won't spill.

Please note that you'll only insert it when removing the funnel - otherwise oil won't go into levers, obviously.

Wide end is not to be inserted into funnel - you'll only use the "sharp end" to block the funnel.

Comment: This is incorrect. The wide end of the oil stopper, supplied with the small rubber O-ring, is to be used to block the funnel when removing it from the handle. The sharp end **does not** block the flow. If you do not have a funnel at hand to try that yourself, see the manual SI-0061A-002-00 (from which the image is taken).

Comment: You two might be looking at different examples - that there's an O ring designed into the end implies it is intended to seal against something.   Perhaps photos might clarify this.

Comment: Agree that looking at the manual SI-0061A-002-00 this answer is incorrect